# Missing (TFM) files since MiKTeX update

Tags: fonts, miktex

I use the Cochineal font for both text and math using the packages `cochineal` and `newtxmath` with the option `cochineal`. I use MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10. Everything worked perfectly fine until maybe a week ago, when I updated packages, many named `miktex-...`. Since these updates, when I compile any document that uses the package `newtxmath` with the option `cochineal`, I keep getting errors like

```
Font \csname\endcsname=cochMI at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

The `.pdf` file is still produced in the end, but all math characters based on letters or numbers are missing.

I was totally lost at first, so I just tried to uninstall both `Cochineal` and `newtx` and to reinstall them using the MiKTeX console. Actually I even tried to uninstall and reinstall the whole MiKTeX distribution from my computer.

After lots of research, I tried to verify if Cochineal and newtx were correctly installed (although I'm still not certain that I understand correctly the installation of fonts, it seems kinda complicated). I thought maybe the `.tfm` files from Cochineal or `newtx` had been lost or something, but I was able to find them in the TEXMF root directories; all of the `.tfm` files from Cochineal are under `fonts\tfm\public\cochineal` and all of those from `newtx` are under `fonts\tfm\public\newtx`. I also verified that the `.map` files were saved in the right folders; I have `Cochineal.map` under `fonts\map\dvips\cochineal` and both `newtx.map` and `zmn.map` under `fonts\map\dvips\newtx`. I also did run the `updmap` command in the prompt after installing both fonts.

Here's an example of a small document which produces the error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\( Test \)

\end{document}
```

Maybe it's something quite obvious, but I'm really lost. How to get LaTeX to find the `.tfm` files?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably the postscript fonts names database was not refreshed. In the `Tasks` menu of MiKTeX console, try `Refresh font map files` both as user and as administrator.

Comment: It fails for me too, also in texlive. I will check.

Comment: @Bernard thanks! I tried to refresh both the font map files and (I don't know if it could have been useful) the file name database, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: if is quite probably a bug in the package. Write a mail to the author, he normally corrects this quite fast.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the author of the package, and it was indeed a problem with the version available on CTAN. He sent an update of the Cochineal package, and now everything works fine!